# How to pass a hash to a sub?

Tags: sql, perl, hash, parameter-passing, dbi

In my perl "script" I'm collecting data and building a hashmap. The hashmap keys represent field names, and the values represent the value I want to insert into the corresponding field.

The hashmap is built, and then passed to the saveRecord() method which is supposed to build a SQL query and eventually it will execute it.

The idea here is to update the database once, rather than once per field (there are a lot of fields).

The problem: I'm having trouble passing the hashmap over to the sub and then pulling the fields and values out of the hashmap. At this point my keys and values are blank. I suspect the data is getting lost during the passing to a sub.

The output of the script indicates no keys and no values.

Need help passing the data to the sub in a way that lets me pull it back apart as shown - with `join()`.

Thanks!

Code snippet:

```
for my $key (keys %oids) {
        $thisField = $key;
        $thisOID = $oids{$thisField};
        # print "loop: thisoid=$thisOID field=$thisField\n";

        # perform the SNMP query.
        $result = getOID ($thisOID);
        # extract the information from the result.
        $thisResult = $result->{$thisOID};

        # remove quotation marks from the data value, replace them with question marks.
        $thisResult =~ s/\"|\'|/\?/g;

        # TODO: instead of printing this information, pass it to a subroutine which writes it to the database (use an update statement).
        # printf "The $thisField for host '%s' is '%s'.\n", $session->hostname(), $result->{$thisOID};

        # add this key/value pair to the mydata hashmap.
        $mydata{$thisField} = $thisResult;

        # print "$thisField=$thisResult\n";
}


# write one record update for hashmap %mydata.
saveRecord (%mydata);


# write all fields to database at once...
sub saveRecord ($) {
        my $refToFields=shift;


        my @fieldlist = keys %$refToFields;
        my @valuelist = values %$refToFields;
        my $sql = sprintf ("INSERT INTO mytable (%s) VALUES (%s)",join(",",@fieldlist), join(",",@valuelist) );

        # Get ID of record with this MAC, if available, so we can perform SQL update
        my $recid = getidbymac ($MAC);

        print "sql=$sql\n";
    # TODO: use an insert or an update based on whether recid was available...
        # TODO: ID available, update the record
        # TODO: ID not available, insert record let ID be auto assigned.
}
```

Comment: In general, don't use subroutine prototypes.  They don't work like they do in other languages.  Mostly, they exist so that a module author can duplicate the interfaces of built-in functions.  See perldoc perlsub for more info.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.hmtl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a little. Your main problem was not using a reference when calling your sub. Also note the commented regex which is cleaned up:

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# $thisResult =~ s/["']+/?/g;
my %mydata = ( 'field1' => 12, 'field2' => 34, );

saveRecord (\%mydata); # <-- Note the added backslash

sub saveRecord {
    my $ref = shift;
    my $sql = sprintf "INSERT INTO mytable (%s) VALUES (%s)",
        join(',', keys %$ref),
        join(',', values %$ref);
    print "sql=$sql\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
sql=INSERT INTO mytable (field1,field2) VALUES (12,34)
```

Comment: Very nice, and clean. Thank you TLP!

Comment: This is a good rewrite.  It would have been great answer if you had explained why you made the changes you made.  You pass a reference because of sub argument list flattening.  You ditch prototypes because they aren't desirable here.  You replaced an alternation with a character class because it is easier to read.  You removed unneeded escapes because they were also unneeded.  I don't have room in a comment to fully explain each item, but at least now there are some search terms for the curious.

Comment: @dao Good point. I think the code speaks for itself very well, though.